# How to format a data frame just like gasoline data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use `pls` package to analyse my data in R. 
My data is similar to gasoline data, my data contains many columns of UV data (at different wavelengths) and one column of alum data. gasoline data contains a numeric vector (octane) and matrix with 401 columns (NIR). It seems NIR data is treated as a group. 
I want to formate my data just like gasoline data and use the similar codes as below.

```
library(pls)
data("gasoline")
gas1 <- plsr(octane ~ NIR, ncomp = 10, data = gasTrain, validation = "LOO")
```

A small set of my data as follows:

[image]

I have tried

```
library(readxl)
Data <- read_excel("test.xlsx")
x = as.matrix(Data[,1:6])
y = Data[,7] 
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)
```

but it did not form a dataframe as the gasoline data.

Please help me to format a data format like gasoline data, so I can use the pls code to process my data and use UV data to predict alum. Any suggestion is welcome. Many thanks. :)

gasoline data is obtained from the `pls` package in R.

I used `dput()` function to show my data as below.

```
dput(head(Data))

structure(list(`UV. 200 nm` = c(35.0310061349693, 34.5507472222222, 
34.3612970711297, 33.942698457223, 33.7440041666667, 33.5717955493741
), `UV. 222.5 nm` = c(34.3149110429448, 33.8141833333333, 33.6073877266388, 
33.181190743338, 32.9606347222222, 32.7796870653686), `UV. 225 nm` = c(33.4781748466258, 
32.9576319444444, 32.7334881450488, 32.2993730715287, 32.0620333333333, 
31.870173852573), `UV. 227.5 nm` = c(32.7270429447853, 32.1803916666667, 
31.9470181311018, 31.5060967741936, 31.2553597222222, 31.0520792767733
), `UV. 230 nm` = c(32.0851104294479, 31.5236361111111, 31.2877782426778, 
30.8468849929874, 30.586125, 30.3832002781641), `UV. 232.5 nm` = c(31.1708558282209, 
30.6077847222222, 30.3719414225941, 29.9375497896213, 29.6742291666667, 
29.4762865090403), Alum = c(76.000324025669, 75.95384102484, 
75.9992186218653, 75.9955211469609, 75.9996022222152, 76.0093745773557
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: We would need a [minimal reproducible example][1]  to help you.

 [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello @Linda, please, type in the console `dput(head(gasoline))` and copy the output in your question, so we can understand the dataframe you need.

Comment: gasoline data is obtained from pls package in R.

Comment: I want to apply plsr for my data (UV data and alum data), by following the example codes applying plsr on gasoline data. I am still new to R and don't know other ways to do it.

Comment: I tried dput(head(gasoline)), but the result is very long, so I removed some numbers and wavelengths. the output is:  structure(list(octane = c(85.3, 85.25, 88.45, 83.4, 87.9, 85.5
), NIR = structure(c(-0.050193, -0.044227, -0.0468........ 1.221135, 1.198851, 1.208742, 1.206696, 1.202926, 
1.207576), .Dim = c(6L, 401L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), c("900 nm", "902 nm", "904 nm", "906 nm", "908 nm", 
......"1690 nm", "1692 nm", "1694 nm", "1696 nm", "1698 nm", "1700 nm"
)), class = "AsIs")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @RonakShah, @ Desmond @ Alexis, many thanks for the suggestions. I have edited the question, hopefully it's more clear now. I used dput function on my data and showed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Ronak Shah's answer, you can use more generalised code to implement `pls` like

```
library(pls)
data("gasoline")
gas1 <- plsr(octane ~ ., ncomp = 10, data = gasoline, validation = "LOO")
```

where `octane` is the dependent variable (y) and all other variables were used as indepentednt variables.
Then you can select the optimum number of `ncomp` using following functions

```
selectNcomp(gas1, "onesigma", plot = TRUE)
selectNcomp(gas1, "randomization", plot = TRUE)
```

Likewise for your dataset, you can use the following code

```
pls.fit <- plsr(Alum~., ncomp = 2, data = df, validation = "LOO")
```

where Alum is the dependent variable. Note that the `ncomp` can not be more than the number of independent variables. Ideally, you should select a sufficiently large value for `ncomp` (e.g. 40 or 50) when your independent variables are many(>100) which is typically the case for spectroscopic data. Then you can select the optimum number of `ncomp` or latent variables (LVs) using

```
selectNcomp(pls.fit, "onesigma", plot = TRUE)
selectNcomp(pls.fit, "randomization", plot = TRUE)
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is very helpful! :) @Bappa Das

Answer (score 1):

The pls help file recommends to create a structure like Gasoline in Section 4.2 "Data Frames".  If you do want to do this, using the first lines of your example matrix in a text file:

[image: Sample Data File]

Then use the following sample code.  The multi column matrix should be protected by the 'protect function' I()

```
Data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(dataFile, header=TRUE, sep="\t", check.names = FALSE))
UV = as.matrix(Data[,1:6])
Alum = Data[,7]
df1 <- data.frame(I(UV), Alum)
```

Results are as for the Gasoline object:
[image: Example Results]

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data as matrix in plsr. No need to convert it same as `gasoline`.

For example for the data shared you can use something like this :

```
library(pls)
gas1 <- plsr(Alum~as.matrix(data[-7]), data = data)
```